# TypeOrm Migration Generate Entity Class Error

Tags: typescript, migration, typeorm

I'm trying to implement typeorm migrations to my project to create database and table directly in all environments without running any script on database.

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
    "migration:create": "npm run typeorm -- migration:create ./path-to-migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./path-to-config/typeorm.ts migration:generate ../path-to-migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./path-to-config/typeorm.ts",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./path-to-config/typeorm.ts migration:revert"
```

I have done my implementation based on this source: https://dev.to/amirfakour/using-typeorm-migration-in-nestjs-with-postgres-database-3c75 I have tried lots of solution like setting strictPropertyInitialization to false in tsconfig.json etc but nothing works.typescript version "~5.1.6".

```
 Unable to compile TypeScript:
entity.ts:3:2 - error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'.
```

One thing to add I think it's related to ts-node because when I change typeorm in package.json like   `"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm -d path-totconfig/typeorm.ts"` error is totally different like below:

```
Error during migration run:
Error: Unable to open file: "/path-to-config/typeorm.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
```